# What is the less expensive method of inserting records into Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to be able to repeatedly process an XML file and insert large amounts of data into an Oracle database. The procedure needs to be able to create new records, or update existing ones if data already exists.

I can think of two ways to process inserting/updating 100,000 records into an Oracle database. But which is the better method? Or is there another way?

- Attempt the INSERT. If no exception, the insert works and all is good. If there is an exception, catch it and do an UPDATE instead.
- Look up the record first (SELECT). If not found do an INSERT. If found, do an UPDATE.
  Obviously if the Oracle table is empty then the first method saves time by foregoing lookups. But if the file was previously imported, and then someone changes a few lines and re-imports, then the amount of exceptions generated becomes huge.
  The 2nd method takes longer on an empty database due to lookups but does not generate expensive exceptions during subsequent imports.

Is there a "normal" pattern for working with data like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what 'the' pattern is, but if you are generating a statement, then maybe you can generate a union of `select from dual` queries that contains all the data from the XML file. Then, you can wrap this select in a `MERGE INTO` statement, so your SQL looks something like:

```
MERGE INTO YourTable t
USING (
  SELECT 'Val1FromXML' as SomeKey, 'Val2FromXML' as Extrafield, 'Val3FromXML' as OtherField FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Val1FromRow2' as SomeKey, 'Val2FromXML' as Extrafield, 'Val3FromXML' as OtherField FROM DUAL
  ...) x ON x.SomeKey = t.SomeKey
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
    t.ExtraField = x.ExtraField, 
    t.OtherField = x.OtherField
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ExtraField, OtherField) VALUES (x.ExtraField, x.OtherField)
```

The advantage of this statement, is that it's only one statement, so it saves the overhead of initializing a statement for each row. Also, as a single statement it will completely fail or completely succeed, what you would otherwise accomplish with a transaction.

And that's a pitfall as well. For an import like this, you may want to do only a limited number of rows at a time and then commit. That way you don't lock a large part of the table for too long, and you can break the import and continue later. But fortunately, it should be pretty easy to generate a `MERGE INTO` statement for a limited number of rows too, by simply putting no more than, say, 500 rows in the unioned select-from-duals.

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" pattern would be to wrap your file with an [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) and then perform an [upsert via the merge keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).

Depending on your hardware loading the file into a staging table via SQL*Loader can be much faster than using an external table.

**edit** - just realized you're processing a file and not trying to load it directly. [GolezTrol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591351/99691) is a good way to deal with the rows you're generating. If there's a huge amount though I would still recommend populating a staging table and consider loading it separately via loader instead a massive SQL statement.